# Where does ASDoc get its intrinsic class definitions from?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, actionscript-3, ant, asdoc

I mean that of the built-in ECMA objects: String, Number, Object, Function, RegExp, Error, Boolean, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have found from extensive search on my drive is that it comes from the Flash installation as follows, though it may only be the syntax - highlighting and completion code.

Find your Adobe Flash installation, the following is for CS4, Flash Player 10.

```
c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\FP10\playerglobal.swc
```

Open the above .swc in WinRAR or something equivalent, you will see an XML file that seems to server as a reference, and a SWF file "library.swf" which holds all the code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Correct, native objects come from playerglobal.swc. In the case of asdoc, which is part of the Flex SDK, it will be one of the playerglobal.swc files that come with the SDK (each version of Flash Player has it's own version of this SWC).